# Ошибка: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type. - Раньше такой ошибки небыло и сейчас я не знаю как это решить

Tags: python, sql, discord, sqlite3, type-error

```
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(866061390313029666)
    print(channel)
    print('BotDesire connected!')
# DataBase
    global base, cur
    base = sqlite3.connect('discordDesire.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('DataBase connecte...OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (ClanId REFERENCES User(UserId), ClanroleId, ClanvoiceId, ClantextId, ClanroleName, ClanLeader)'.format('Clans'))
    base.commit()
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (ClanId, UserId, ClanroleName, UserName)'.format('UserClans'))
    base.commit()
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (BossId INT, BossName, BossHp INT)'.format('Boss'))
    base.commit()
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (UserId PRIMARY KEY, UserName, Balance BIGINT, Lvl INT, Dmg INT, DmgLog INT)'.format('User'))
    base.commit()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cur.execute(f'SELECT UserId FROM User WHERE UserId = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO User(Balance, Lvl, Dmg, DmgLog, UserId, UserName) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (0, 1, 1, 0, {member.id}, {member}))
                base.commit()
            else:
                Pass
```

Error:
File "C:\Users\artur\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\DiscordDesireBot.py", line 43, in on_ready
cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO User(Balance, Lvl, Dmg, DmgLog, UserId, UserName) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (0, 1, 1, 'qwe', {member.id}, "{member}"))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cur.execute(f'SELECT UserId FROM User WHERE UserId = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO User(Balance, Lvl, Dmg, DmgLog, UserId, UserName) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (0, 1, 1, 0, member.id, str(member)))
                base.commit()
            else:
                pass
```

Я глупый немного но решил проблему просто изменением поля member на строковое и все решилось)

Comment: Всё верно, так как объект `member` передаётся здесь в типе `str`, а в sql str значения указываются в ковычках